# Crypted passwords in PHP-apis? Twitter?

Tags: encryption, twitter, passwords

I'm creating a small service using api-libraries, such as Twitter. Is it possible to input users password to Twitter-api crypted. I would not like to store peoples passwords uncrypted on my server, but writing them every time is annoying.

Does someone know?

Martti Laine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using [OAuth](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/OAuth-FAQ).
[Here](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/OAuth-Examples) are some examples.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP you can use the [GnuPG extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php) to easily encrypt **any credentials** on your side, and decrypting them before making the API calls.

Here's a check list of things you need:

1. make sure gpg is installed on your system;
2. create a gpg key pair and store the files on a safe location;
3. optionally password protect the generated private key;
4. use PHP's GnuPG extension to encrypt and decrypt data using those keys.

Here's a small PHP example, taken from the gnupg_encrypt() manual:

```
<?php
$res = gnupg_init();
gnupg_addencryptkey($res,"8660281B6051D071D94B5B230549F9DC851566DC");
$enc = gnupg_encrypt($res, "just a test");
echo $enc;
?>
```

This technique should also be applied **even if you're using OAuth** or other password-less authentication method. A common mistake is to use OAuth and not encrypt locally saved tokens as access to those tokens might give anyone the power to act on behalf of the user.